# I get bad address when trying to run execve

Tags: c++11, valgrind

So I am trying to a vector of strings that contain arguments that I want to try and run with execve command. I am also copying the environment because the application that I am writing needs to have a copy of the incoming environment from the process. This application is written in c++, and I am getting an error that is "Bad Address" from the execve call. Here is the current code that I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

int main (int argc, char * argv[], char * envp[]) {

    int total = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    char **my_array;
    char **my_envp;

    // Setup copy the environment.
    while (envp[a] != NULL) {
        total++;
        a++;
    }

    my_envp = new char*[total+1];

    for (a = 0; a < total; a++) {
        my_envp[a] = new char[strlen(envp[a])+1];
        strcpy(my_envp[a], envp[a]);
    }
    a++;
    my_envp[a] = NULL;

    // Get my path and arguments.
    vector<string> random = { "/bin/echo", "Grace ", "Will ", "Dan ", "Scott ", "Kevin ", "Amanda " };
    my_array = new char*[random.size()+1];

    for (b = 0; b < random.size(); b++) {
        my_array[b] = new char[strlen(random[b].c_str())+1];
        strcpy(my_array[b], random[b].c_str());
    }
    b++;
    my_array[b] = NULL;

    // Run my arguments.
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (execve(my_array[0], my_array, my_envp) == -1)
            perror("");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        waitpid(pid, 0, WUNTRACED);
    }

    // Clean up time.
    for (b = 0; b < random.size(); b++) 
        delete [] my_array[b];

    delete [] my_array;

    for (a = 0; a < total; a++) 
        delete [] my_envp[a];

    delete [] my_envp;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Valgrind output:

```
{"
==27594== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27594== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27594== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27594== Command: ./a.out
==27594== 
==27594== Invalid write of size 8
==27594==    at 0x40115A: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27594==  Address 0x5ab6eb0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 560 alloc'd
==27594==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (o)
==27594==    by 0x40106E: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27594== 
==27594== Invalid write of size 8
==27594==    at 0x4014E0: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27594==  Address 0x5ab9220 is 0 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==27594==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) ()
==27594==    by 0x4013D1: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27594== 
==27595== Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==27595==    at 0x549E777: execve (syscall-template.S:84)
==27595==    by 0x40151D: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27595==  Address 0x5ab9218 is 56 bytes inside a block of size 64 alloc'd
==27595==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) ()
==27595==    by 0x4013D1: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27595== 
==27595== Syscall param execve(envp) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==27595==    at 0x549E777: execve (syscall-template.S:84)
==27595==    by 0x40151D: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27595==  Address 0x5ab6ea8 is 552 bytes inside a block of size 560 alloc'd
==27595==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) ()
==27595==    by 0x40106E: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27595== 
Grace  Will  Dan  Scott  Kevin  Amanda 
==27594== 
==27594== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27594==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==27594==   total heap usage: 80 allocs, 79 frees, 77,249 bytes allocated
==27594== 
==27594== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27594==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27594==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27594==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27594==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==27594==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27594== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not show
==27594== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==27594== 
==27594== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27594== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
"}
```

I have a feeling that the way I am creating the char pointer of cstring pointers is not correct, or I am missing something very obvious. Thanks.

Comment: the arguments list must end with `NULL`, yours does not

Comment: How do I add a NULL terminator without getting errors in Valgrind?

Comment: What has valgrind to do with that? You do `my_array = new char*[random.size() + 1];` and after the loop making the copies, you do `my_array[b] = NULL`

Comment: And add an `exit(1)` in the child process after the `if`, otherwise if `execve` fails, the child process doesn't run code not intended for the child process to run.

Comment: I added the valgrind output at the top Pablo, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Remove the `b++;` before `my_array[b] = NULL;`, otherwise you are accessing the memory out of bounds. Same goes for `a++` before `my_envp[a] = NULL;`

Comment: Also why do you do a copy of `envp` when you can pass that variable directly to `execve`? This is unnecessary.

Comment: Well I mentioned in the description above that I have to copy it for the full application and I have to increment the iterator for the next element to be NULL. Also I am not going out of bounds because I am adding one to the size of both the arguments and the environment. Thanks.

Comment: But `fork()` "makes" already a copy of all variables, you don't need to an extra copy, just pass it to `execve`.

Comment: But its not just execve needing the copy of the environment, everything else in the application also needs to have access to it. So I want to copy the environment.

Comment: And why not accessing `envp` directly? I don't see the point of the copy. But if you copy it, then you must do it right, I already wrote how.

Comment: I compiled your code removing the incorrect `a++` and `b++` and valgrind reports no errors.

Comment: Well apparently from valgrind that your way is not correct.

Comment: No, valgrind is telling you that you are accessing memory out of bounds, and they come because you have a `a++` and a `b++` to much. I said remove it, but if you ignore that, then of course your valgrind will give you errors

Comment: I think our conversation keep getting mixed up every time we typed over each other. Okay so I removed the a++ and b++ from ending of both loop, but why did I have too? If I allocated the size of the environment and arguments, and added another element to either array (with my_envp[a] = new char[strlen(envp[a])+1];, and my_array = new char*[random.size()+1];) for the NULL element, how is it going out of bounds? I don't want the last element from the loop to get over written with a NULL terminator?

Comment: *I removed the a++ and b++ from ending of both loop, but why did I have too?*  I addressed that in my answer.

Comment: Okay I just saw the updated post that you provided. Sorry for being stubborn, I just wanted a reason. I wish I could up vote on your answer! Have a great day.

Comment: It's nothing wrong for asking for more clarification, here we were a little bit desynchronized in our conversation. But you can upvote answers of your questions at any time but with reputation 1 you would need to wait (I think it's 15 minutes) to accept an answer.

Comment: Will make sure to do so, because that was such a noob mistake. Thanks Pablo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code was that neither your environment list nor the
argument list was `NULL` terminated. Then you made an update of your code from 
my suggestion:

> What has valgrind to do with that? You do `my_array = new char*[random.size() + 1];` and after the loop making the copies, you do `my_array[b] = NULL`

but you did it **incorrectly**:

```
for (a = 0; a < total; a++) {
    my_envp[a] = new char[strlen(envp[a])+1];
    strcpy(my_envp[a], envp[a]);
}
a++; // <-- does not belong here
my_envp[a] = NULL;

for (b = 0; b < random.size(); b++) {
        my_array[b] = new char[strlen(random[b].c_str())+1];
        strcpy(my_array[b], random[b].c_str());
}
b++; // <-- does not belong here
my_array[b] = NULL;
```

and valgrind is complaing about that:

```
==27594== Invalid write of size 8
==27594==    at 0x40115A: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27594==  Address 0x5ab6eb0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 560 alloc'd
==27594==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (o)
==27594==    by 0x40106E: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27594== 
==27594== Invalid write of size 8
==27594==    at 0x4014E0: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
==27594==  Address 0x5ab9220 is 0 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==27594==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) ()
==27594==    by 0x4013D1: main (in /home/examples/a.out)
```

The correct version should be (as I wrote in the comments)

```
for (b = 0; b < random.size(); b++) {
        my_array[b] = new char[strlen(random[b].c_str())+1];
        strcpy(my_array[b], random[b].c_str());
}
my_array[b] = NULL;
```

The reason why you don't need the `b++` is because the loop is already doing it.

For a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    printf("i in loop: %d\n", i);
}

printf("i out of loop\n");
```

you will get

```
i in loop: 0
i in loop: 1
i in loop: 2
i in loop: 3
i in loop: 4
i out of loop: 5
```

because the loop ends when the condition evaluates to false, and this happens
when `i == 5`. The same applies for the `for` loop above, if you increment `b`
once again after the loop ends, you are increment to much.

So let's say `random.size()` is 5 (like in my loop example) and you've allocated
space for `random.size() + 1 == 6` elements, so you can only index from memory
from 0 to 5. At the end of the loop `b` is 5, if you do an extra `b++` then `b`
is 6 and 6 is beyond the bound of `my_array`.

To prove that, this is the code I compiled

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

int main (int argc, char * argv[], char * envp[]) {

    // these variables must be unsigned, vector.size()
    // returns an unsigned value
    unsigned int total = 0;
    unsigned int a = 0;
    unsigned int b = 0;
    char **my_array;
    char **my_envp;

    // Setup copy the environment.
    while (envp[a] != NULL) {
        total++;
        a++;
    }

    my_envp = new char*[total+1];

    for (a = 0; a < total; a++) {
        my_envp[a] = new char[strlen(envp[a])+1];
        strcpy(my_envp[a], envp[a]);
    }
    my_envp[a] = NULL;

    // Get my path and arguments.
    vector<string> random = { "/bin/echo", "Grace ", "Will ", "Dan ", "Scott ", "Kevin ", "Amanda " };
    my_array = new char*[random.size()+1];

    for (b = 0; b < random.size(); b++) {
        my_array[b] = new char[strlen(random[b].c_str())+1];
        strcpy(my_array[b], random[b].c_str());
    }
    my_array[b] = NULL;

    // Run my arguments.
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (execve(my_array[0], my_array, my_envp) == -1)
            perror("");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        waitpid(pid, 0, WUNTRACED);
    }

    // Clean up time.
    for (b = 0; b < random.size(); b++) 
        delete [] my_array[b];

    delete [] my_array;

    for (a = 0; a < total; a++) 
        delete [] my_envp[a];

    delete [] my_envp;

    return 0;
}
```

and the output

```
$ g++ a.cpp -oa -g -Wall 
$ valgrind ./a 
==15833== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15833== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15833== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15833== Command: ./a
==15833== 
Grace  Will  Dan  Scott  Kevin  Amanda 
==15833== 
==15833== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15833==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15833==   total heap usage: 79 allocs, 79 frees, 78,730 bytes allocated
==15833== 
==15833== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15833== 
==15833== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15833== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```